# figure out IF two lines intersect in $2D$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am working on my GRE and I came across a question that gives me the function 
$f(x) = |2x| + 4 $

then asks me which functions will intersect $f(x) = |2x| + 4$

a) $g(x) = x - 2 $

b) $g(x) = x + 3$

c) $g(x) = 2x - 2$

d) $g(x) = 2x + 3$

e) $g(x) = 3x - 2$

I know how to find out **where** two lines will intersect, but not **If** two lines will intersect,

a step wise procedure would be helpful as I haven't taken a math class in > 10 years

I can Ass-u-me, that the lines will intersect if the slope is greater than the one given and is headed towards the one given, such as answer choice E, however I would really like a definitive procedure for knowing with certainty and without graphing as the GRE doesnt allow that

thanks to anyone who helps :)

Comment: If you can find where two lines intersect then try to find where they intersect if you can't seem to find it then most likely they don't intersect

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to find the answer (e) is to notice that line (e) is the only one that is steeper than the given $f(x)$ graph. The line with a larger coefficient $k$ of the term $kx$ will be steeper.

In general, it helps to sketch a graph of the given function(s) and then use your knowledge of graphs of elementary functions (linear, quadratic, etc. as the case may be).

Comment: so is it safe to say that if a line has a slope that is steeper than the one given and heads towards it (a negative y intercept moving towards a line with a positive y intercept ) it will intersect ?   thanks for the reply

Comment: The simple case is: two *lines* intersect at a point if they have different slopes. However, an additional problem in your particular question is that you have one "absolute value" graph $f(x)$ and another line. Here, the line with a steeper slope *must* intersect the absolute value graph with a less steep slope. All other lines (a)-(d), at first glance, *may or may not* intersect $f(x)$. A more detailed examination reveals that neither of (a)-(d) intersects $f(x)$; but for test purposes it's enough to notice that (e) *must* intersect $f(x)$.

Comment: okay so just to make sure I am getting this, because an absolute value graph is basically a line going both left and right (positive and negative slopes) starting at the y-int, any line with a slope steeper than the one given will eventually intersect it? yes?

Comment: Yes, any *line* with a slope steeper than the one given in *the absolute value graph* $f(x)$ will eventually intersect $f(x)$.

Comment: Thanks alex!! This was a really short and to the point explanation !

Answer (score 0):

i will demonstrate the solution for a) in the case $$x\geq0$$ we have to solve
$$2x+4=x-2$$ from here we get $$x=-6$$ which is impossible.
In the case $x<0$ wer have to solve $$-2x+4=x-2$$ and we get $$x=2$$ thus we get no intersection points.

Comment: wait, couldnt you just plug in your now solved x to find the y values and thus get a point of intersection ?

Comment: if the $x$ value not exists, then also the $y$ value.

Comment: okay thank you for the detailed reply, very helpful !!!

Answer (score 0):

First define the function $f(x)$ piecewise :

$$ f(x) = \Big\lbrace \begin{align} 2x+4 ~~ \text{if} ~~x>0\\
\ -2x+4 ~~ \text{if} ~~x<0 \end{align}$$

Now solve it with each line and also look whether it satisfies $x>0$ or $x<0$ , according the line chosen by you.

For example take $2x+4$ and solve it with each line and check for $x>0$, similarly for $-2x+4$.The line which passes through any of the above criteria
will be your answer.

---

Although, there is another better way to approach through graph, but I think it would be better for you to use the above specified method as you seem to be a beginner.

Comment: Thanks Jaideep!! this makes sense, it seems I didnt really know what an absolute value graph meant !!!

Answer (score 0):

We have that $|x|\geq x$ from this for $a$ you get $|x|-2\geq x-2$ and for b $|x|+3\geq x+3$ etc.
Now $|2x|+4$ is bigger then any of the options a,b,c,d I will prove this for $a$ you have $$|2x|+4>|x|-2\\|x|>-6$$
Which is always true,I'll leave the options b,c,d for you to prove,for e you can find the intersection.